# How do I solve 'Data tag parsing failed: Trailing data...' errors in Minecraft commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a sign that gives you a book that says the following:

> Rule 1: Use RELEASER book to release the seeker. This book is obtained by pressing the Hiders button
>   Rule 2: Don't use commands that weren't provided by the map.
>   Rule 3:Have fun(jk rage I'm evil HAHAHAH).

The title of the book is Rules and the Author is RebornSquid

This is what I typed in the command block (I'm making a map with a group of friends)

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"[{\"text\":\"*right click*\",\"color\":\"blue\"}]",Text2:"[{\"text\":\"Rule Book\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:[{\",text\":\"Rule 1: Use RELEASER book to release the seeker. This book is obtained by pressing the Hiders button\\nRule 2: Don't use commands that weren't provided by the map\\nRule 3: Have fun(jk rage I'm evil HAHAHAH)\"}"}\]",title:Rules,author:RebornSquid}\"}}]"}
```

This is the message I'm getting:

```
[22:54:04] Data tag parsing failed: Trailing data found at: ...fun(jk rage I'm evil HAHAHAH)\"}"}\<--[HERE]
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: You should first fix your give command before trying to use it in other commands. From what I see there are too many brackets inside `pages:[ ]`

Comment: While the other question is certainly helpful it doesn't address the problem completely. Not all commands use strict JSON like tellraw does.

Comment: @dly can you show me what the command you think should look like after you comment that would be very helpful thanks

Comment: @Robotnik I am making a command for a sign that says *right click* on line 1 and on line 2 Rules Book. This command will make the sign so that if you right click on it it will give you the rules book and the rules are stated above I edited the Question.

Answer (score 3):

I see several problems with your command.  The biggest one I always see with complicated double commands like this is always special character escapement.  I will get to that last as it is the most complicated.  If you see three dots `...`, this means I omitted data to make the problem easier to see.

1. You have square brackets around the text line sections for the sign:

   - `{Text1:"[{...}]",Text2:"[{...}]"}`
   - Should be `{Text1:"{...}",Text2:"{...}"}`
2. The give command has several problems:

   - `\",text\"` there should be no comma
   - The general structure of the give command is wrong:

     - `{pages:[{"...":"..."}"}\]",title:...,author:...}`
     - Should be `{pages:["{"...":"..."}"],title:...,author:...}`
     - You are missing a quotation mark before the first curly bracket, you have an extra curly bracket which screws up parsing, a slash before the square bracket, and a quotation mark after the square bracket.
3. Escapement problems

---

**Escapement**

Special characters have to be escaped when inside quotation marks.  In your case, you have to escape quotation marks and you have to escape slash marks.

This is very simple when things are only escaped one time:
`{Text1:"..."}`. All special characters which are inside the Text1 quotation marks have to be escaped 1 time: `Text1:"{\"text\":\"...\",\"color\":\"...\"}`

It gets more complicated when you have quotation marks inside of more quotation marks.  This requires double escapement.  In the next example, Text2 is the first set of quotes and the click event value quotes are the second set.  This requires the pages quotation marks to be double escaped.

```
Text2:"... \"/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:[\\\"...\\\"] ... \" ..."
```

Double escapement means you need to escape once. Then escape the character and all escapement slashes a second time.  `"` => `\"` => `\\\"`

Anything inside of the pages quotation marks requires triple escapement.  All special characters have to be escaped again, this includes the slashes to escape the characters.  `\\\"` is double escaped, there are 4 characters to escape which adds 4 slashs for a final `\\\\\\\"`.

Finally, within pages the text requires another set of quotation marks which require quadruple escapement for anything inside.  In this case the new line (`\n`) has a slash which needs quadruple escapement.

- Original: `\n`
- Double: `\\n`
- Triple: `\\\\n`
- Quadruple: `\\\\\\\\n`

---

Finally, the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"*right click*\",\"color\":\"blue\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Rule Book\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:[\\\"{\\\\\\\"text\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Rule 1:Use RELEASER book to release the seeker. This book is obtained by pressing the Hiders button\\\\\\\\nRule 2:Don't use commands that weren't provided by the map\\\\\\\\nRule 3:Have fun(jk rage I'm evil HAHAHAH)\\\\\\\"}\\\"],title:Rules,author:RebornSquid}\"}}"}
```

Here is the command but the book is reformatted to look a little better:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"*Right Click*\",\"color\":\"blue\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Rule Book\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:[\\\"{\\\\\\\"text\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Rule 1:Use RELEASER book to release the seeker. This book is obtained by pressing the Hiders button\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\nRule 2:Don't use commands that weren't provided by the map\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\nRule 3:Have fun\\\\\\\\n(jk rage I'm evil HAHAHAH)\\\\\\\"}\\\"],title:Rules,author:RebornSquid}\"}}"}
```

---

**Building complex commands**

A good point that D-Inventor brought up.  When building these commands, start with a small piece of the big picture.  Verify it works by testing each change in game.  When verified functional, add more.

To fix your command, I completely reworked the entire command.  I started by creating a functional give command.  If you test your give command, it will not execute properly.  Once I had the give command functioning, I created a setblock command which would set a wall sign.  Then I made that setblock command add the first line of text, then the second line, then the color, then a command, then the give command.  I tested the command at each step.  By doing it this way, you know when errors are introduced.  Just remember to note the last functioning command so you can back up if needed.

If you don't want to memorize structure, you can use generators.  You could use [this book editor](http://minecraft.tools/en/book.php) to produce your give command and then stuff that command into [this command sign generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/command-sign-generator).  **However**, you will most likely have to modify the final command you are given as it will probably have escapement problems.  The sign generator even contains a note:

> Note: The sign generator is somewhat fragile. If something does not work try adding a preceding \ to your special chars.

Comment: A general advice would be to build nbt data in small steps and test with each iteration. I thought that would be worth mentioning as well. Your answer is great though, have a +1 from me

Comment: @D-Inventor Thank you.  I agree completely.  I added a section to mention that process.